# Can't resolve dependencies with Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to compile a newly created Play Project and I can't due to dependency issues.

Although I'm connected to the internet, I'm getting the following errors.
Any ideas?

```
D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal>activator run
[info] Loading project definition from D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\project
[info] Set current project to rsvp-portal (in build file:/D:/Git_Work/RSVP/rsvp-portal/)
[info] Updating {file:/D:/Git_Work/RSVP/rsvp-portal/}root...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.1.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/twirl-api_2.11/1.1.1/twirl-api_2.11-1.1.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\twirl-api_2.11\1.1.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\twirl-api_2.11\1.1.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\twirl-api_2.11\1.1.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/twirl-api_2.11/1.1.1/twirl-api_2.11-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/twirl-api_2.11/1.1.1/twirl-api_2.11-1.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.11/1.1.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-server_2.11/2.4.1/play-server_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-server_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-server_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-server_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-server_2.11/2.4.1/play-server_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-server_2.11/2.4.1/play-server_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-server_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-java_2.11/2.4.1/play-java_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-java_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-java_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-java_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-java_2.11/2.4.1/play-java_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java_2.11/2.4.1/play-java_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-java_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-netty-server_2.11/2.4.1/play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-netty-server_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-netty-server_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-netty-server_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-netty-server_2.11/2.4.1/play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-netty-server_2.11/2.4.1/play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-netty-server_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-java-jdbc_2.11/2.4.1/play-java-jdbc_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-java-jdbc_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-java-jdbc_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-java-jdbc_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-java-jdbc_2.11/2.4.1/play-java-jdbc_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java-jdbc_2.11/2.4.1/play-java-jdbc_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-java-jdbc_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-cache_2.11/2.4.1/play-cache_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-cache_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-cache_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-cache_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-cache_2.11/2.4.1/play-cache_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-cache_2.11/2.4.1/play-cache_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-cache_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-java-ws_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-java-ws_2.11/2.4.1/play-java-ws_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-java-ws_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-java-ws_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-java-ws_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-java-ws_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-java-ws_2.11/2.4.1/play-java-ws_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-java-ws_2.11/2.4.1/play-java-ws_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-java-ws_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-test_2.11/2.4.1/play-test_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-test_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-test_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-test_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-test_2.11/2.4.1/play-test_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-test_2.11/2.4.1/play-test_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-test_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.11;2.4.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Read timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-omnidoc_2.11/2.4.1/play-omnidoc_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.11;2.4.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\naviyehezkel\.ivy2\local\com.typesafe.play\play-omnidoc_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-launcher-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-omnidoc_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn]   D:\Java\typesafe-activator-1.3.4\activator-1.3.4\repository\com.typesafe.play\play-omnidoc_2.11\2.4.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/play-omnidoc_2.11/2.4.1/play-omnidoc_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/play-omnidoc_2.11/2.4.1/play-omnidoc_2.11-2.4.1.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/play-omnidoc_2.11/2.4.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.1.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-java-ws_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-server_2.11:2.4.1 ((play.sbt.PlaySettings) PlaySettings.scala#L55)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-java-ws_2.11:2.4.1 (D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\build.sbt#L9-14)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-test_2.11:2.4.1 ((play.sbt.PlaySettings) PlaySettings.scala#L63)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-java_2.11:2.4.1 ((play.sbt.PlayJava) Play.scala#L44)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-omnidoc_2.11:2.4.1 ((play.sbt.PlaySettings) PlaySettings.scala#L69)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc_2.11:2.4.1 (D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\build.sbt#L9-14)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-netty-server_2.11:2.4.1 ((play.sbt.PlayNettyServer) Play.scala#L68)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:play-cache_2.11:2.4.1 (D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal\build.sbt#L9-14)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.11:1.1.1 ((play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl) SbtTwirl.scala#L71)
[warn]            +- rsvp-portal:rsvp-portal_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.1.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.11;2.4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.11;2.4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.11;2.4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.11;2.4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java-ws_2.11;2.4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.4.1: not found
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.11;2.4.1: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.11;1.1.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-server_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-netty-server_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java-jdbc_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-java-ws_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.11;2.4.1: not found
[error] Total time: 193 s, completed 13:28:48 28/06/2015

D:\Git_Work\RSVP\rsvp-portal>
```

I'll appreciate your help!

**EDIT:**
I got the same errors while trying to run "activator run" & "activator compile".

Comment: *"Server access Error: Read timed out [..]"* ... so check your network settings.

Comment: I've tried to "ping" the some of the addresses and got response. In addition, I was able to access the "pom" using the browser..

Comment: It looks like none of your dependencies resolve. Maybe check your version numbers. They might not exist.

Comment: @Kris - thanks for the comment. Do you mean the version number of the dependencies (2.4.1)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 5):

*I know this question is for play 2.4, but I was getting a similar error with play 2.5 (especially the part where it **could not resolve twirl**)*

In play 2.5, the latest version of scala supported is 2.11.11, so if you are using scala version 2.12, you should change it to 2.11.

In build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
```

After that, in sbt I type `reload` followed by `compile` and everything was working well again